# Solspace Tracker - Any way to order results?

Tags: solspace, solspace-tracker

Looking at the Tracker Control Panel, is there any way to order the tables for Overall Statistics, Site Averages, or Entry Statistics? It seems intuitive to click the column heading for that, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions